# Rearranging a table in tsql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

So I have a table with the following columns:

```
Type    Test    Min     Max
-----------------------------
  1     a        1       2
  1     b       Null    Null
  2     a        0      Null
  2     b       Null     1
```

Trying to get all of them like this

```
Type   Test1  Test1 min  Test1max  Test2 Test2min Test2max
------------------------------------------------------------
 1      a       1           2       b     Null       Null
 2      a       0         Null      b     Null        1
```

Tried using unpivot first before I use pivot but it's still giving duplicate tests and removing null any help with this is much appreciated
Need null values to show up as well

```
Select type, result
(
From 
Select type, min
From table t
)
Unpivot
(result for minmax in (min1)
)
```

Select 
Thanks

Comment: Edit your question and show the query you have attempted using `pivot`.

Answer (score 0):

using `row_number()` and conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    [Type]
  , Test_1     = max(case when rn = 1 then Test end)
  , Test_1_Min = max(case when rn = 1 then Min  end)
  , Test_1_Max = max(case when rn = 1 then Max  end)
  , Test_2     = max(case when rn = 2 then Test end)
  , Test_2_Min = max(case when rn = 2 then Min  end)
  , Test_2_Max = max(case when rn = 2 then Max  end)
from (
  select *
    , rn = row_number() over (partition by [Type] order by [Test]) 
  from t
  ) as s
group by s.Type
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/BKL48976

returns:

```
+------+--------+------------+------------+--------+------------+------------+
| Type | Test_1 | Test_1_Min | Test_1_Max | Test_2 | Test_2_Min | Test_2_Max |
+------+--------+------------+------------+--------+------------+------------+
|    1 | a      |          1 | 2          | b      | NULL       | NULL       |
|    2 | a      |          0 | NULL       | b      | NULL       | 1          |
+------+--------+------------+------------+--------+------------+------------+
```

Comment: I have multiple types(over 15) and tests(over 10), is there a simpler way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from table t1
join table t2 
  on t1.type = t2.type 
 and t1.test < t2.test
```

Comment: I need null values returned as well

Comment: This would return all of the rows in the sample data set.  Do you have rows where `type` or `test` are null?

Comment: There are no null values in the posted data.

Comment: Sry, no nulls in the tests and types field...but this still gives me the same result I had before, which is a different row for each test

Comment: No it does not.  t1.test < t2.test